# Select form item has undefined value

Tags: javascript, html, hoisting

I have read a little about hoisting, but I am not sure how it applies in this situation. I have a select value that is shown and hidden dynamically and the value of this select element is always undefined. Please help! Thanks

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>Type:</td>
    <td>
        <select id="type" onchange="rulesShown()">
            <option value="ATC">ATC</option>
            <option value="PILOT">PILOT</option>
        <select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="rules">
    <td>Rules:</td>
    <td>
        <select id="rules">
            <option value="FAA">FAA</option>
            <option value="ICAO">ICAO</option>
        <select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function rulesShown() {
        if(document.getElementById("type").value=="ATC"){
            document.getElementById("rules").style.display = "";
            document.getElementById("rules").style.removeProperty( 'display' );
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("rules").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    function verifyData() {
        var email1 = document.getElementById("email1");
        var email2 = document.getElementById("email2");
        var comments = document.getElementById("comments").value;
        if(comments!=""){
            if(email2==null){
                    //submit form
                    submit();
            }
            else if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email1.value)){  
                if(email1.value == email2.value) {
                    //submit form
                    submit();
                }
                else {
                    //emails dont match
                    alert('Email addresses do not match!');
                }
            }
            else{
                //invalid email address
                alert('Please enter a valid email address!');
            }
        }
        else{
            alert('Please enter some comments!');
        }
    }
    function submit(){
        var vid = <?php echo $user['vid'] ?>;
        var email = document.getElementById("email1").value;
        var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
        var rules = document.getElementById("rules").value;
        var comments = document.getElementById("comments").value;
        var xhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhttp.open("POST", "/content/training/request/submit.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("vid="+vid+"&email="+email+"&type="+type+"&rules="+rules+"&comments="+comments);
    }
</script>
```

No need for the file the AJAX is calling. It simply POST's the 'rules'. As far as I can tell this is a javascript hoisting problem, but I don't know why. Thanks

Comment: why do you think this is a problem related to hoisting and not related to the fact that `.value` is not a valid property of the object returned by `document.getElementById()`?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with hoisting which is pure javascript concept. You have two elements with same id. A `<tr>` and a `<select>`. Which is forbidden by html. One of the implications of this is that browser doesn't guarantee which element will be returned by `getElementById()`